# Trouble Mounting a Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcsfuse

I am trying to mount this public bucket into my Google cloud shell:

```
gs://mssng-share/released/genomes/ILMN/VCF/*Using mount point: 

/home/serdarrowanalytics/mount
```

I tried:

```
gcsfuse mssng-share ./mount
```

however, i get flagged with this error message.

```
Opening GCS connection...
Opening bucket...
Mounting file system...
daemonize.Run: readFromProcess: sub-process: mountWithArgs: mountWithConn: Mount: mount: running fusermount: exec: "fusermount": executable file not found in $PATH

stderr:
```

Comment: What was your question?

Comment: When I run this GCSFuse on Google Shell it does not complete the task of mounting a bucket and replies  "fusermount": executable file not found in $PATH

Comment: second problem: I also tried running it on my local server, and it says "successfully mounted!" but then the directory I mounted the bucket to is empty.

Comment: my question is what I should do differently, or if there are other trouble shooting ideas. I use a very simple command which is:gcsfuse bucket mountdirectory

Comment: If you see this after building and trying to run `gcsfuse` in a Docker container (or in general), one possibility is you just forgot to install `fuse`, which is a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Following the [tutorial provided by Google](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse), I was able to mount a bucket successfully in my cloud shell.
I followed the [install instructions](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/installing.md) linked from the Google article.

### Commands were as follows (starting in my home directory ~/):

```
export GCSFUSE_REPO=gcsfuse-`lsb_release -c -s`

echo "deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt $GCSFUSE_REPO main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gcsfuse.list

curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install gcsfuse

mkdir -p ./path/to/mount
```

### Then ran command:

```
gcsfuse [bucket name (no prefix or suffix)] ./path/to/mount
```

And it worked.

I had to “sudo su” to enter the directory, but the contents were mounted.

Without steps to reproduce this error, I cannot provide a guaranteed answer. It would all be speculation based on existing articles found through a Google search.

This is not a bug in the cloud shell.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I did the same thing. It says "successfully mounted"

Comment: However, the mount directory is empty.

Comment: rowus@bashful:/home/jim$ gcsfuse mssng-share ./mnt
Using mount point: /home/jim/mnt
Opening GCS connection...
Opening bucket...
Mounting file system...
File system has been successfully mounted.
rowus@bashful:/home/jim$ ls
rowus@bashful:/home/jim/mnt$ ls
ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error

Comment: I tried mounting a few buckets. The mount folder is always empty.

Comment: io errors are usually caused by hardware issues. Can you confirm this is happening on your cloud shell?

Comment: I have not been able to mount on the shell or my local server.

Comment: You said " It says "successfully mounted"", then you mentioned the directory was empty, then you showed you were getting an IO error. Then you said you are not able to mount on cloud shell or local server? I am confused.

So, are you able to mount on the cloud shell? What errors are you receiving on the cloud shell? Do you have files in your bucket? I cannot help with an IO error on a local machine.

Comment: I've done some research, but everything related to your error is related to Docker. No other programs, other than Docker, are getting this error, & it seems like the Docker issues are resolved based on syntax. I've also failed to reproduce this error. Are you running as root? Also, how large is the file in your bucket? How many files do you have of what type? Following the tutorial, can you mount on a fresh GCE instance? How about using a different bucket? My suggestion is to uninstall & reinstall GCS fuse on your cloud shell. If you can provide reproduction steps I can look further into it.